# Python Calling Function from Another File

Tags: python, function

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 Professional.

I am trying to call a function saved in another file to run in `this file`'s code.

Function called `dosomething` is found in `anotherfile.py`

`anotherfile.py` is in the same directory as current code.

My call in `this file` is simple:

```
import anotherfile

print anotherfile.dosomething
```

I am getting an error: `No module named anotherfile`

The problem is the same as I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058827/calling-a-python-function-from-another-file)

I don't understand the solution but I'd like any insight?

Thank you.

EDIT:  The other question/answers discuss resetting CLASSPATH and setting PYTHONPATH.  I explored this but was not sure how to do this.  Perhaps relevant?

Comment: `anotherfile.dosomething()` since it's a function

Comment: When I do this I get `NameError:  name 'anotherfile' is not defined`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us have two files in the same directory. Files are called `main.py` and `another.py`.

First write a method in `another.py`:

```
def do_something():
    return "This is the do something method"
```

Then call the method from `main.py`. Here is the `main.py`:

```
import another
print another.do_something()
```

Run `main.py` and you will get output like this:

```
This is the do something method
```

N.B.: The above code is being executed using Python 2.7 in Windows 10.

Comment: Check if both files are in same directory and ensure there is no directory with the same filename

Comment: Both files are in the same directory.  It is a new computer and there are no files with the same name in other directories.

Answer (score 6):

Specify the module then the file then the import like so:

```
from this_module.anotherfile import dosomething
```

or if you want all functions from "anotherfile.py"

```
from this_module.anotherfile import *
```

and then you can call the "dosomething" command without the "anotherfile" prefix.

Comment: what specifically is `this_module`?  I'm in 'this file' and have lines of code.  No functions (yet)

Comment: "this_module" would refer to the app that you are working in. For example, "mysite" would be a module. (essentially, the directory)

Comment: sorry to be dense.  I'm coding this up in Spyder.  Would I somehow incorporate path to reference the directory?

Comment: Could you possibly post your directory structure on here for me to see?

Comment: `C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Scripts`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143410/discussion-between-andrew-and-windstorm1981).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem. After ample of trials, I ended up solving it with the below mentioned solution:

Make sure your current file and anotherfile.py lies in same location of system path.
Say your another.py and current file lies at location : "C:/Users/ABC"
In case, one is not aware of system path. Use below code in current file:

```
  import sys
  print(sys.path)

  import sys
  sys.path.append('/C:/Users/ABC/')
```

Then you do below code in same current code:

```
  from another import dosomething
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Python was looking in another directory for the files.  I explicitly set my working directory as the path to where `thisfile.py` and `anotherfile.py` reside and it works.  Thank you for all the quick replies.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you explicitly set it?